# What are use cases of insert mode in Vimium and where is it documented?

Tags: vimium

I love Vimium and finally started to look into more of its features, but I just wasn't able to find anything on how it can be useful at all. For example, Visual mode is nicely documented in [the Wiki](https://github.com/philc/vimium/wiki/Visual-Mode) but all I could find about insert mode so far is how to enter and exit it. Tried random keys I know from using Vim but none seemed to have effect.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

The use case of insert mode (entered while pressing `i`) is documented [in the README](https://github.com/philc/vimium/blob/master/README.md#keyboard-bindings):

```
> i     enter insert mode -- all commands will be ignored until you hit Esc to exit
```

This may be useful to temporarily disable keybinds so it does not conflict with webpages implementing their owns.

Examples:

- Using [AsciiFlow](https://asciiflow.com/) while Vimium is enabled is fine, but as soon as one wants to enter text into the diagram, Vimium will hijack the relevant keystrokes. Turning on insert mode solves this.
- YouTube controls (e.g., `<` and `>` to decrease or increase playback speed, `t` for theater mode) can also trigger Vimium, but insert mode will prevent this happening.

Comment: So a better name is Bybass Mode or Disabled Mode ?

Comment: @toraritte I think you hit the nail on the head. It's insert mode in the sense that it lets you type normally, as in vim's insert mode.